# Pandas Change time string in a column to 24 hour time format

Tags: python, pandas, time

hi all I have a column df['TimeEnd'] where these are the string values and I am trying to convert them to 24 hr time format. What will be the easiest way to do it?

```
Time End  Counts
1058PM    56
0501PM    26
1145PM    24
1125PM    24
0605PM    20
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
df['Time End'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time End'], format='%I%M%p').dt.strftime('%H:%M')
print (df)
  Time End  Counts
0    22:58      56
1    17:01      26
2    23:45      24
3    23:25      24
4    18:05      20
```

If there are wrong values like `1300PM` add `errors='coerce'` for misisng values if no match, convert to format with `H` (24H format) instead `I` (12H format) and repalce possible misisng values by parsed datetimes `d2`:

```
print (df)
  Time End  Counts
0   1300PM      56
1   0501PM      26
2   1145PM      24
3   1125PM      24
4   0605PM      20

d1 = pd.to_datetime(df['Time End'], format='%I%M%p', errors='coerce')
d2 = pd.to_datetime(df['Time End'], format='%H%M%p', errors='coerce')

df['Time End'] = d1.fillna(d2).dt.strftime('%H:%M')


print (df)
  Time End  Counts
0    13:00      56
1    17:01      26
2    23:45      24
3    23:25      24
4    18:05      20
```

Comment: Thanks but I am getting this error ValueError: time data '1300PM' does not match format '%I%M%p' (match)

Comment: @DDM - hmm, so it means `1300PM` is incorect? Beause corerct should be `0100PM` for `13:00`